# Error While creating a new Rails Project in Rails 5.0.0.rc1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to create a new Rails project, based on chapter 3 of Michael Hartl's RubyonRails.

Anytime I try to create the sample_app I get this message:

```
$ rails _5.0.0.rc1_ new sample_app                                            
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (= 5.0.0.rc1) - did find: [railties-4.2.2] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
```

It looks like it is not adding the new app gems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have the `railties` gem from Rails 4. There's an updated version for Rails 5. When you use the `rails new` command you're using your system's gem versions, *not* those specified in the Gemfile. So you can try:

```
gem uninstall railties
gem install railties -v 5.0.0.rc1
```

Comment: yah, it seems that I am running 4.2.6 railties. I tried the uninstall - install : it reinstalled the same version :  Fetching: activesupport-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.6
Fetching: actionview-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-4.2.6
Fetching: actionpack-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-4.2.6
Fetching: railties-4.2.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed railties-4.2.6
4 gems installed

Comment: OK in that case when you install, specify the new version. `gem install railties -v 5.0.0.rc1`

Comment: Awesome ! That works. I learned something today. Thank you so much Max !